# Assign value to textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i have a radio button([StarRating radiobutton](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/) using jquery) and a textbox. When i click on the star, i would like the radiobutton value to display to the textbox.

`<input id="InsRating1" class="star" type="radio" name="InsRating" value="1" title="Worst"/>

 <input id="InsRating2" class="star" type="radio" name="InsRating" value="2" title="Good"/>`

I tried put the Onclick() in the  but onClick() has never get fired. 
Please advice how to get the value from my radiobutton to textbox. Thanks

I tried this below, but the value is "Undefined"

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#InsRating1').click(function() {
        alert(this.value)

    });

});
```

**-------------Edit----------**
I am using g_thom's answer below but come to this problem :
I have 3 set of stars with 3 textboxes. Each rating should show to only 1 textbox.
However whenever any star is clicked, it shows the value to all 3 textboxes instead of just specified one. Please advice. Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

$(function() {
    $('.star-rating').click(function() {
        // assign the value of "total stars" to a textbox with an id of ratingText
        $('#EvaluationInstructorRatingTextBox').val($('.star-rating-on').length);
    });
    $('.rating-cancel').click(function() {
        // the value is '0' when the cancel button is clicked
        $('#EvaluationInstructorRatingTextBox').val('0');
    });

```
$('.star-rating').click(function() {
    // assign the value of "total stars" to a textbox with an id of ratingText
    $('#EvaluationMaterialRatingTextBox').val($('.star-rating-on').length);
});
$('.rating-cancel').click(function() {
    // the value is '0' when the cancel button is clicked
    $('#EvaluationMaterialRatingTextBox').val('0');
});


$('.star-rating').click(function() {
    // assign the value of "total stars" to a textbox with an id of ratingText
    $('#EvaluationValueRatingTextBox').val($('.star-rating-on').length);
});
$('.rating-cancel').click(function() {
    // the value is '0' when the cancel button is clicked
    $('#EvaluationValueRatingTextBox').val('0');
});
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the inputs are converted to divs (with the 'rated stars' being assigned a different class), I think you'll want to count the number of divs with the `.star-rating-on` class and assign that value to the input, like this:

```
$('.star-rating').click(function() {
    // assign the value of "total stars" to a textbox with an id of ratingText
    $('#ratingText').val($('.star-rating-on').length);
});
```

Boring looking example - without the actual graphics/animations (just the HTML from the transformed inputs on plugin page - the value will always be 4): http://jsfiddle.net/bhf2d/

**EDIT**

The code above should work. I think you may be thinking that you need to apply your jQuery to the radio button, but that's not the case, since it is swapped out on page load with a div. Just in case you're not clear, I've added a live example using the code you provided in your question: [Click here to see it](http://bjornthomson.com/testtabs/star-rating/index.html).

**EDIT 2**

See [an updated version here](http://bjornthomson.com/testtabs/star-rating/index2.html), matching the additional requirement to set multiple checkboxes. The textboxes have been renamed slightly (InsRatingText0 etc) to facilitate easily adding more items. The name convention `InsRatingText[n]` is set that way to match the div classes the plugin adds dynamically ('rater-0', 'rater-1', etc)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i got  "[object Object]" when i do `alert(  $('#InsRating1').val(($('.star-rating-on').length)));`

Comment: I can't see your html, but with this plugin, isn't your "#InsRating" input converted to a div with the class ".star-rating"?

Comment: If you inspect the 'inputs' on the page http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/ with FireBug or Chrome's "Inspect Element," you'll see what I mean.

Comment: The inputs are changed to divs dynamically when the page loads - so targeting the input id="InsRating1" won't work.

Comment: I think everyone is telling you the same thing :)

Comment: You have been working a fantastic work here. Now i see the divs changed dynamically when page load. Thanks so much.

Comment: Got a question here, i have 3 set of stars with 3 textboxes. Each set of stars should display the value to only 1 textbox. However your current way is shown to all 3 textboxes when a star is click. Can i determined each set by the name instead?
 `$('input[value="InsRating"]').click(function() {    
     $('#EvaluationInstructorRating').val($('.star-rating-on').length);      
 });
 $('.rating-cancel').click(function() {    
     $('#EvaluationInstructorRating').val('0');
 });


`

Comment: To clarify more, when i click on a star, the value of it will display to all the 3 textboxes instead of just the EvaluationInstructorRating Textbox which i specified ` $('#EvaluationInstructorRating').val($('.star-rating-on').length);    `

Answer (score 0):

These `<input>` elements are not clicked, since they are hidden and replaced by `<div>` elements. You should use `onChange()` events instead.

Also, radio button do not use the property `value`, but `checked`.

Comment: do you meant add the onChange ="test()" to the <input ...> ?

Comment: Yes, or, using jQuery to assign change events : `$("#snuf").change(cb);`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$(function (){
    $(".star").click(function(){
       $("#textbox1").val($(this).val());
     });
});
```

Basically, it is adding a handler for onclick to the eloement with class ="star" and then copying that value to the textbox.

Comment: I tried your code as this `$(function (){
    $(".star").click(function(){
       alert($("#InsRating1").val($(this).val()));
     });
});`,  but i got this "[object Object]".

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".star").bind('click', function() {
  $("#ratingValue").val($(this).text())
});
```

Seems like getting the val() on the checkbox didn't work, but using text() gives the value. Here is the example working: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasalguero/pHrTK/)

Comment: I just noticed, val() doesn't work because the checkbox is replaced by a div with a link inside

Comment: Thanks, But what if i have 3 set of Stars with 3 textboxes? I have updated my question.  Thanks